# Wordpress redirect loop issue, admin panel lockout; change admin settings without wordpress admin panel

Tags: php, wordpress, heroku

While editing settings in my wordpress admin panel I locked myself out.  I specifically changed the Wordpress site address field from http to https.  I figured if I had problems I would be able to unset after but now when I try to get to the admin panel I am in a redirect loop like so.

```
http://some_app.herokuapp.com/wp-admin/
302 Redirect
https://some_app.herokuapp.com/wp-admin/
302 Redirect
https://some_app.herokuapp.com/wp-admin/
302 Redirect
https://some_app.herokuapp.com/wp-admin/
....etc
Error Tracing URL
Error: There were too many redirections in trace.
```

I don't understand why it would redirect to the same page repeatedly.  Is there any way to change the values in the admin panel without access?

I attempted to modify these lines in my wp-config.php

```
if (getenv("WORDPRESS_SITEURL")) {
    define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://some_app.herokuapp.com/');
```

but it did not appear to have any effect on the redirection.

Comment: Try removing from the conditional statement, and add the additional WP_HOME: 

define('WP_HOME','http://some_app.herokuapp.com/');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://some_app.herokuapp.com/');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being a very strange issue, and I think the result of some very poor naming.  With regard to heroku wordpress setup this is what was needed:

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://some_app.herokuapp.com');  /** real heroku location **/
define('WP_HOME', 'http://www.main_site.com/blog/'); /** presentable url users see **/
```

WP_SITE_URL refers to  "WordPress Address (URL)" in the admin settings panel

and

WP_HOME refers to "Site Address (URL)"